# Keras - getting Labels as strings from directory structure

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to write a CNN in keras. My dataset consists of 20,000 images in 250 classes with the following folder structure:

```
dataset/
    class1/
        1.png
        2.png
        ...
    class2/
        ...
    ...
```

From my understanding the easiest way to load the images/labels is to use a combination of [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) and `flow_from_directory()`.
Minimal working example:

```
from keras.layers import Activation, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # input image dimensions
    img_rows, img_cols = 225, 225
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 15, 15, input_shape=input_shape, subsample=(3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.compile(loss='hinge', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])

    data = ImageDataGenerator()
    train_data = data.flow_from_directory(directory='dataset', color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(img_rows, img_cols))
    model.fit_generator(train_data, 100, 12)
```

This however stops with the following error:

```
Exception: Error when checking model target: expected maxpooling2d_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 250)
```

with 32 being the `batch_size` and 250 the number of classes.

Is this a problem with how I retrieve my Images/Labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was not the labels being strings, but a wrong CNN architecture. Adding a `Flatten()` layer after the `MaxPooling2D` I am now able to map the net's output to my labels.